# jQuery mobile slider validation

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider

Is there any way to prevent invalid input in the value field of slider in jQuery Mobile? for example in [this](http://oi43.tinypic.com/s64mcn.jpg) image you see that user can enter * or # character, I want user can only enter numerical value.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number Support Code in jquery

```
   $('.Number').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode;

    keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 27 || keycode == 9 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
        event.preventDefault();
       alert("Enter Numbers Only");
        return false;
    }
    else {            
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dinesh, but I don't know where this code should be inserted?

Comment: put this code in $(document).ready(function () { code here }); then give class name as Number which field you need to validate. . .